# Global sections functor commutes with tensor product for $\Gamma$-acyclic sheaves?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space, and $A$ a ring. Let $F,G$ be sheaves of $A$-modules on $X$ which are acyclic for the global sections functor $\Gamma$. Is it true that
$$\Gamma(F\otimes G) = \Gamma(F)\otimes_A\Gamma(G)?$$

Comment: What if $X=\{a,b\}$ and $F=G=A$ which are acyclic since $X$ is discrete. Then $F\otimes_A G=A$ and on one hand $\Gamma(X,F\otimes_A G)=A^2$. On the other hand, $\Gamma(X,F)\otimes_A\Gamma(X,G)=(A^2)\otimes_A (A^2)=A^4$. For a connected example $Y$, choose two points $a\neq b$ and write $i:X\to Y$ the inclusion. Then take $F=G=i_*A$.

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/105232/tensor-product-of-sheaves-separated